# how to merge tax table into an existing sentence

Tags: sql

I have the following sentences in the first table:

- key     desc
- single  The single standard deduction for {2018} is {12000}.
- MFJ     The MFJ standard deduction for {2018} is {24000}.

I want to merge {info} from the second table:

- key           value
- single*2018   12000
- mfj*2018      24000

I want to be able to have a place holder {2018} so a select join can show the description in the first table to change when tax years are changed ie from 2018 to 2019.

Comment: What could you possibly mean by "sentence"?  People sometimes confuse that with "query", but that doesn't make sense here either.  Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would help clarify.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "fact" when you say "sentence?" It is still unclear to me what you are describing or asking.

Comment: MFJ = Marriage Filing Joint ?

Comment: the table has key and desc....desc is the value for the sentence:  "The single standard deduction for {2018} is {12000}."   I want to replace {2018} and {12000} when the year change to {2019} and {15000} and update the place holder in the first table.